# Is the new X-files a reboot?

Tags: the-x-files

I saw some stories online today (http://www.news.com.au/entertainment/tv/the-xfiles-early-buzz-what-the-critics-are-saying/news-story/c6fe70af335ae9c9c8cf2495584e741b) referring to the new 6 part mini series of the X-files as a "reboot".

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but I thought a reboot was when a story starts all over again, ignoring everything that's come before it in terms of continuity.

I thought the new 6 episodes were a continuation of the original story, and thus not a reboot.

So are the new episodes a reboot or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a resumption - not a reboot, technically speaking, because the same actors are returning to the same show.

From the Fox website:

> **Season 10** - the highly anticipated event series **returning** to FOX in January - See
>   more at:
>   http://www.fox.com/the-x-files?cmpid=ppc_goog_FOX_xfiles_ss_2015#sthash.hPhtwX9U.dpuf

The original series ended after the 9th season, so listing Season 10 on the website indicates it is a resumption of the same series.

The use of the term 'reboot' can be used differently but this is a revival, not a from scratch do-over

Comment: Thanks for that. I got worried when I saw it referred to as a reboot.

Comment: People also call *The Office* a spoof documentary, when it’s actually a mock-documentary. And these are people who write for a living. Words are their only job. My rage cannot be described.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I can actually understand saying spoof documentary vs mockumentary for The Office because I think in a strict defintion of the term 'mock' there is an emphasis on contempt or harsh criticism of the genre itself whereas with a spoof it is more good natured / farce using the same medium / method

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell: oh, I thought it was the other way around — “spoof” being something that mocks the form being imitated (i.e. a fake documentary that makes fun of documentaries, whether it does so harshly or not), whereas “mock” in this sense actually just means “fake” or “imitation”. Words is hard.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - words is hard indeed - likely being a portmanteau, mockumentary probably has no speficic meaning other than the intent of the user and can be used interchangeably for the most part. Good question for English SE maybe?

Comment: Definitely a continuation, not a reboot. Not only do the same actors reprise their original characters, but there are many references to events from the original series (and movies) in the new season.  Examples include Mulder & Scully's child, Cancer Man's disfigurement, and the ongoing efforts of the US government to fake alien encounters among the general populace.